# Can the next function after Array.prototype.map() safely assume all callback in map have returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, mapping

I know `Array.prototype.map` is a synchronous operation. On the other hand if the map function is a callback function (asynchronous) `undefined` will return immediately.

So my question is can the next function safely assume all callback functions have been done?
A sample code may make my question more clear :

```
results = files.map(file => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return process(file) //will return the processed value, NOT a promise
  });
)
//I know results will be [undefined, undefined, undefined ...]
//But can I assume all the files have been processed if I reach here?
console.log('done')
```

I don't care about the return values. That is why I don't want to bother with `await/async`. I just want to make sure all callback functions have called and returned. Is that possible ?

------- update --------

In additional to the answer I found these articles also help me understand the problem:
https://medium.com/@antonioval/making-array-iteration-easy-when-using-async-await-6315c3225838
[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

I have to use promise to make sure all callback iteratees have finished. So using [bluebird promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) helps to reduce boilerplate codes

Comment: You actually `return` nothing from the arrow func, therefore it is undefined, if you return the promise you could use `Promise.all` on the returned array.

Comment: I don't want to use await b/c I can't care about the mapped array I just want to know if all callback functions are returned. What is the "correct" way to do it ?

Comment: @JonasWilms my sample code was wrong (I have corrected it) I do return in my arrow function but I believe I still get an array with all undefined items. I think my question is different from what you mentioned in the other two questions.

Comment: Agreed, its not a real dupe, apologies

Comment: @Qiulang no, `map` does not ensure that any callbacks have been called, in fact, it *doesn't even know* about the asynchronous callbacks you passed to `readFile`. It only cares about the return value of the `map` callback itself, which is `undefined`. Just go and use promises, you still can ignore their results - but you need them to be able to wait for them.

Comment: @Bergi double confirm., thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the callback function promising, then you can use Promise.all:

```
 const results = Promise.all(files.map(file => new Promise(resolve => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    resolve(process(file));
  });
 ));

 results.then(() => {
   console.log('done')
   //...
 });
```

Comment: That is what I have been trying to avoid in the first place. I know I can use promise.all/await but I don't want to!  Because all I need is to make sure the next function after map can safely assume all callbacks have done and hence the question.

Comment: @qiulang this is the only way. Or you use `fs.readFileSync` but that would be very slow

Comment: But I did some test, e.g. print the processed value before return in each callback and found those prints always run before my next function. I know I shouldn't count on that but on the other hand b/c map is sync and I still wonder if that is the possible

Comment: @quilang as I said, if you want it to run synchronously use `fs.readFileSync`